# How to setup AzureDevops Selfhosted agents in Azure ContainerAppservice?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-container-apps

We are using Azuredevops server and looking for a way to run our self hosted Build agents in Azure ContainerAPP service as this will support KEDA. But looking in Microsoft documents, there is no guidance to create it and couldnt find any good article on how to create the ADO self hosted agents in AzureContainerApp with private access.

Is anybody achieved this in your envireonments or tried? Please help me with the steps if you have achieved this already.